# Arrays, Structs, Functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I need to make a struct. Then make an array holding 7 of these structs. Then pass it through 3 functions and change the value of the struct array within the functions and pass it back to main.
I know how to make a struct. So let's go with this:

```
struct election{
   char name[20];
   int votes;
   };
```

I'm assuming making an array would be:

```
struct election electionCandidates[6];
```

In order to pass through a function. How would I do this? And is it easier to return the struct array or should I pass it through as a pointer?

This may be completely incorrect, but I always feel like people are more willing to help if they can see that I am actually trying to do this problem and not just asking for help because I a lazy or something.

```
void Initialize(election *electionCandidates[]);
```

Or maybe this?

```
struct election Initialize(struct electionCandidates[]
```

Thank you for any helpful comments.

Comment: `void Initialize(election electionCandidates[]);`. Using this, you are already passing `electionCandidates` as a pointer, so you can change whatever you want in the contents of those structures, and you don't need to return anything from the function.

Comment: `void initialize(election electionCandidates[], int numberOfCandidates);`

Comment: or `void Initialize(struct election *electionCandidates);`

Comment: `struct election electionCandidates[6];` allocates only 6 structs, numbered from `[0]` to `[5]`. You want to write `[7]` when allocating the struct, but remember that the index of the last allocated struct is then only `[6]`. In what you wrote, the last index would be `[5]`.

Comment: Ok. And when I call this function in main it would like like              Initialize(&electionCandidates);   Correct?

Comment: `Initialize(electionCandidates);`

Comment: Alright, thanks guys! I have to sit down and work with my code now. I'll get back to you if I have anymore questions!

Answer (score 0):

```
   void Initialize(election *electionCandidates[]);
```

Syntax is wrong: you have to say `struct election`.
On the other hand, you are declaring there a parameter having type "pointer to array of struct election", but you need "array of struct election".

So, the correct version is:

```
  void Initialize(struct election electionCandidates[]);
```

Since in function arguments every array declaration "decays" to pointer, it would be equivalent to:

```
  void Initialize(struct election *electionCandidates);
```

The following syntax is also wrong:

```
  struct election Initialize(struct electionCandidates[]
```

The correct is:

```
  struct election Initialize(struct election electionCandidates[])
```

However, this form doesn't look as logical because you are returning only 1 `struct`. Which and why?

The array elements of the parameter `electionCandidates` can be modified and recovered without any problem by `main()`, so a `void` return here seems right.

Maybe, it would be better to define an alias for the type `struct election`:

```
  typedef struct election election_t;
```

Then we write:

```
  void Initialize(election_t electrionCandidates[])
```

It would be very desirable that you pass the number of candidates as a second parameter, since the function has no way to determina the array size:

```
  void Initialize(election_t electrionCandidates[], int num)
```

Then you make the call in this way:

```
  Initialize(electionCandidates, 6);
```

Here, the "magic" number 6 is the number of elements in your array.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'll let you know if it works!